# Issue with a char* array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

Okay so I have:

```
char* arr[5];
```

and I have

```
char input[10];
```

and then:

```
int i = 0;
cin.getline(input, 10);
while(input[0] != 'z')
{
    arr[i] = input;
    cin.getline(input, 10);
    i++;
}
```

the result is that every element in arr is the same because they are all pointers to input, but I want each element to point to char arrays that the input variable held at that given time.

result that this brings:

```
arr[0] = line beginning in 'z' (because that is what input currently is holding)
arr[1] = line beginning in 'z'
arr[2] = ... and so on
```

result that I want:

```
arr[0] = first line read in
arr[1] = second line read in
arr[2] = third line read in and so on...
```

I am confused about how I can get the elements to all point to new values instead of all be pointing to the same value.

Comment: Stop now with `char *` and use `std::string`.  You'll be glad you did.

Comment: I can't. It is a stipulation in the project I am working on.

Comment: @Smartypants - `It is a stipulation in the project I am working on.` So you're learning `C` instead of `C++`.  Great.

Comment: just for this first project xD

Comment: @Smartypants - So what else can't you use?  Maybe you should state up front what parts of the `C++` language and library are off-limits (as ridiculous as that sounds).

Comment: Yes I should have stated that, I apologize. The answer given below about creating new char arrays and copying the data over was sufficient. Thanks

Comment: @Smartypants - Realize that those answers didn't emphasize that you need to deallocate the memory yourself, else you get a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, yes I deallocated and everything is working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's talk characters and pointers.

Given a character:

```
+---+  
+ A +  
+---+
```

A pointer to the character, `char *`, points to the character.  That's it, nothing more.

An array of characters is a container that has slots for characters.  A pointer to the array often points to the first character of the array.  Here's where the problem comes in.

Many functions require a pointer, *to the first character of the array*, but either don't say that it's to the first character or require a pointer to a single character, assuming that the pointer is the first character in the array.

### Pointers need something to Point at

You have allocated an array of pointers, but haven't allocated the memory for each pointer:

```
Array
+-----+      +----+---+---+  
|     | -->  |    |   |   |  
|     |      +----+---+---+  
+-----+ 
|     |      +----+---+---+
|     | -->  |    |   |   |  
|     |      +----+---+---+  
+-----+
```

The content of the array are pointer.  So you will need to allocate memory and place the pointer into the array:

```
  arr[0] = new char [11]; // +1 for the nul terminator character.
  char text[33];
  arr[1] = text;
```

So what you aim to do is:

```
  cin.getline(arr[0], 10);
  cin.getline(arr[1], 33);
```

Strings are soooo much easier to deal with.  They manage their own memory:

```
  std::string array_text[5]; // An array of 5 string.
  getline(cin, array_text[0]);
```

The next step is to use a `vector` and you are all caught up:

```
  std::vector< std::string > text_vector(5);  // Pre-allocate 5 slots.
  getline(cin.text_vector[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take input 5 times,you can try this code segment

```
int i = 0;
while(i<5)
{
    arr[i] = input;
    cin.getline(input, 10);
    i++;
}
```

this should work and you can get your "desired result" as you stated above.

Edit:
This will not work, as described in the comment.  See example here: http://ideone.com/hUQGa7

What is required are different pointer values occupying each of the elements in `arr`.  How to achieve those different pointer values is discussed in the other answers given.

Comment: This will not work.  You're storing a pointer that never changes, so at the end, you wind up with the last data entered for all entries in arr.  See here: http://ideone.com/hUQGa7

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the data of input everytime.

You can do like this in while loop:

```
while(input[0] != 'z')
{
    arr[i] = new char[strlen(input)];
    strcpy(arr[i], input);

    cin.getline(input, 10);
    i++;
}
```

And since you have defined `arr` to be of length `5`. So you have to check in the while loop that `i` doesn't exceed the value 5. `i<5`.